# Background reconnect parameters on Android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am trying to figure out exactly what Android is doing on its background reconnect on BLE.  For instance, if I issue a connectGatt() with autoConnect set to true, how often does Android look for this? How about when my app is in the foreground?  Background?  Is there any way to manipulate this parameter?

What I have found so far are these:

http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/packages/apps/Bluetooth/src/com/android/bluetooth/gatt/ScanManager.java#490

However, these are separated out into "SCAN_MODE" and "SCAN_MODE_BATCH", but I can't figure out when each of them is used.  I also can't figure out which scan mode is being used for background reconnection.

The closest thing I found to actual information was this:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanSettings#SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER

This says that all scans when the app is backgrounded is done in low power.  But does that include reconnect scans?  And *which* low power mode is it?  The `SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER_INTERVAL_MS` is only 5 seconds, but the `SCAN_MODE_BATCH_LOW_POWER_INTERVAL_MS` is 150 seconds!!  This is quite a difference, and would affect the app quite a bit trying to reconnect to a device.

Anyway, I tried to read through the code, but couldn't figure out exactly what was going on.  Any insights into how this works would be helpful.

The reason I'm asking is that I am having trouble reconnecting to a device on occasion, but the device only wakes up for 30 seconds at a time to advertise.  If Android's scan interval is 150 seconds, they could easily be missing each other in that way.  Any help is appreciated, as well as other reasons why a reconnect might not be successful (note - this is working 100% in iOS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scan manager code does not control the scan parameters for initiating connections.

The code that controls background connections is in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/bt/+/refs/heads/master/stack/btm/btm_ble_bgconn.cc. It references https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/bt/+/refs/heads/master/stack/include/btm_ble_api_types.h which contains:

```
/* default scan paramter used in reduced power cycle (background scanning) */
#ifndef BTM_BLE_SCAN_SLOW_INT_1
#define BTM_BLE_SCAN_SLOW_INT_1 2048 /* 1.28 s   = 2048 *0.625 */
#endif
#ifndef BTM_BLE_SCAN_SLOW_WIN_1
#define BTM_BLE_SCAN_SLOW_WIN_1 48 /* 30 ms = 48 *0.625 */
#endif
```

So the scan window is 30 ms and the interval is 1.28 seconds. If your advertising interval is 20 ms (before adding the random delay of 0 to 10 ms), that means it should not take more than 1.28 seconds to connect (unless the controller uses another scheduling).

Comment: Thank you so much!